# MATLAB-based Java program

Tags: java, android, matlab, matlab-deployment

I am in the process of designing a MATLAB-based algorithm. Is it possible to call that MATLAB source code from a Java application?

Has anyone come across such a issue?

Comment: Though not in matlab but there are implementations of OpenCV in java and android(http://code.google.com/p/android-opencv/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/). This program allows you to convert your matlab code into java classes.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to call MATLAB from Java using [matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com). It's a Java API designed specifically for that. However, it requires MATLAB to be running on the same machine that the Java code is executing on. As you put the Android tag I assume you want to run this on an Android device (although not mentioned in your description), and there is no known way to directly run MATLAB code on Android. matlabcontrol definitely will not do that, but you could use it to write a Java application which acts as a server for your Android application. Similarly, you could do the same with MATLAB Builder JA which generates code that needs either MATLAB or the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (which is available for free - so users would not need to buy MATLAB).